# Getting all siblings together in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to get all siblings together in following code:

```
father_child(tom, sally).
father_child(john, alfred).
father_child(george, peter).
father_child(tom, dick).
father_child(john, harry).
father_child(george, eliz).
father_child(tom, james).
father_child(john, ron).
father_child(george, hermoine).

siblings(X, Y):-  father_child(Z, X), father_child(Z, Y), X @< Y. 

?- findall([X,Y], siblings(X,Y), L).
L = [[alfred, harry], [alfred, ron], [dick, sally], [dick, james], [harry, ron], [eliz, peter], [eliz, hermoine], [james|...], [...|...]].
```

But it gives only pairs. If I did not know how many siblings are there and I want have a list of lists of siblings (as follows), how can I manage?

```
[[a, b, c], [d, e], [x, y, z, w]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `setof/3` or `bagof/3`. This is a good example of something that those can do that `findall/3` cannot (easily). With nothing but the `father_child/2` table defined:

```
?- bagof(C, father_child(F, C), Siblings).
F = george,
Siblings = [peter, eliz, hermoine] ;
F = john,
Siblings = [alfred, harry, ron] ;
F = tom,
Siblings = [sally, dick, james].
```

You can of course nest this inside a `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(Siblings,
           bagof(C, father_child(F, C), Siblings), 
           Ss).
Ss = [[peter, eliz, hermoine], [alfred, harry, ron], [sally, dick, james]].
```

You should try and see what happens if you use `bagof/3` instead of `findall/3`. (Hint: using `findall/3` like this is the same as writing `bagof(Siblings, F^bagof(C, father_child(F, C), Siblings), Ss)`)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.